# How to calculate the numpy.histogramdd bins coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I'm using numpy.histogramdd to bin 3d points. My goal is to count how many bins contains items, and its distance from a specific point is less than a constant. numpy.histogramdd returns binedges, which is "a list of D arrays describing the bin edges for each dimension", but it's not straightforward to find the bins coordinates. Is there a better (and with less loops) way to do it than my following approach?

```
hist_bin_centers_list = [binedges[d][:-1] + (binedges[d][1:] - binedges[d][:-1])/2. for d in range(len(binedges))]
indices3d = itertools.product(*[range(len(binedges[d])-1) for d in range(len(binedges))])
ret_indices = []
for i,j,k in indices3d:
    bin_center = [bin[ind] for bin,ind in zip(hist_bin_centers_list, (i, j, k))]
    if hist[i,j,k]>0 and cdist([pos], [bin_center])[0] < max_dist:
        ret_indices.append((i,j,k))
return len(ret_indices)
```

Thanks to @DilithiumMatrix proposal, here is a better implantation:

```
bin_centers = list(itertools.product(*hist_bin_centers_list))
dists = cdist([pos], bin_centers)[0].reshape(hist.shape)
hits = len(np.where((hist > 0) & (dists < approx))[0])
```

Comment: Is your histogram sparse?  I.e. is hist[i,j,k] == 0 often?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just using [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)?

e.g. combine the two conditions together:

```
nonzero = numpy.where( (hist > 0) & (binDist < max_dist) )
```

where you calculate an array of distances `binDist`, such that `binDist[i,j,k]` is the distance from bin `i,j,k` to `pos`.